# "Files" (Nautilus) not opening from dock

Tags: gnome, nautilus

First time Ubuntu Gnome user here! For some reason, "Files" (Nautilus?) will no longer open from the dock. When I click on "Files", nothing happens at all.

However, when I run `nautilus .` from terminal, I receive the following:

```
(nautilus:12419): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2.10.0
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
Error loading document: Error opening file: Permission denied

(nautilus:12419): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Unable to create loader for mime type application/pdf: Unrecognized image file format

(nautilus:12419): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Error creating thumbnail for file:///usr/bin/fix-qdf: Unrecognized image file format
^[[Aroot@JW-UBUNTU:/usr/bin# nautilus .

(nautilus:12445): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2.10.0
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
```

Unfortunately, this is a bit above me for the moment. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: try removing the dropbox plugin and/or any other plugins/addons to diagnose if it's an issue caused by one of them instead of the package or the system files/packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still unsure as to the exact cause of this, but 'solved' my problem by doing `killall nautilus`, then clicking on "Files" again.

Comment: killall nautilus didn't work for me :|

Comment: this solved my issue with a fresh installation of ubuntu 16.04. After installing a bunch of packages (including gnome shell), the 'files' menu stopped working. thanks!